# How to use spring.data.rest.enable-enum-translation in Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.3, Spring Data REST, HATEOAS, Hibernate.
In my model sometimes I'm using enum like:

```
    public enum Roles {
    ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER, ROLE_MANAGER, ROLE_TECH
}
```

According to Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), there is a property that seems useful:

```
# DATA REST (RepositoryRestProperties)
spring.data.rest.enable-enum-translation=true
```

I didn't find documentation about how to use that. I found old references where seems I should add something like:

```
roles.role_admin=Amministratore
```

in my messages.properties. That would be cool but it doesn't work and my REST reply contains enum value shown like in the class, without any translation.
Could someone explain me the right way to use this function of Spring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use this feature you have to add a 'rest-messages' Resource Bundle to your project 'resources' folder. Then describe your enums in these files like this:

```
com.example.myproject.myapp.Roles.ROLE_ADMIN=Amministratore
com.example.myproject.myapp.Roles.ROLE_USER=Utente
```

If you have a nested enums you have to join them and the parent class with '$' sign:

```
com.example.myproject.myapp.User$Roles.ROLE_ADMIN=Amministratore
com.example.myproject.myapp.User$Roles.ROLE_USER=Utente
```

In the same manner you can describe your links:

```
_links.user.title=Utente
_links.users.title=Lista utenti
```

Then you get something like this:

```
"_links": {
    "user": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1",
        "title": "Utente"
    }
}

"users": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users{?page,size,sort}",
    "templated": true,
    "title": "Lista utenti"
}
```

There is also a [little bit info](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#metadata.alps.descriptions) in the SDR reference regarding to this issue.

See [Restbucks example](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks/tree/master/src/main/resources).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Tomorrow I will try that. Does this feature work backwards? I mean, let's say an Angular app got this REST response with translated enum. When the Web app save the user passing the translated enum, does the server understand it? Thanks

Comment: Don't know but i'm sure it works. Please give a feedback when you try...